# Change Spinner Text Size Programmatically

Tags: android, layout, size, spinner

have a SeekBar and I get the value of it whenever I scroll it. the position should then be the factor, how big the text in my spinner should be.

So I want to change the text size of my spinner items whenever I scroll not the 50sp as in my layout

My custom_list_row.xml

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/textViewRow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="top|left"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
    android:paddingRight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingRight"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:textSize="50sp" />
```

My Adapter

```
ArrayAdapter<Language> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Language>(this, R.layout.custom_list_row,
                currentLanguages);
        spinnerLanguage.setAdapter(adapter);
```

the Language class is a Object with a toString method.

```
@Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        resizeViews(progress);
    }

private void resizeViews(int progress){
    textViewFirstName.setTextSize(20+progress);
    //how can I do this for a spinner here?
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this.

```
private void resizeViews(int progress){
textViewFirstName.setTextSize(20+progress);
//this might be helpful
for(int i=0;i<spinnerLanguage.getChildCount();i++){
((TextView)spinnerLanguage.getChildAt(i)).setTextSize(20+progress);
}
}
```